# Dealing with cascading collisions?

Tags: php, mysql, user-experience, cascade, collision

I have a setup where we have categories,

Each category has a title and a parent_id.

When a category is created/edited we check to ensure that no category that has the same parent_id has the same name.

That is easy.
But now I am working on deleting the categories.

The categories can have unlimited levels. so, if we delete a category it's child categories get moved up to the categories parent. which is working fine, but I don't know what to do in that instance when a collision occurs.

Should I do a precheck on the delete page and disable the delete button and have something like:

> This category cannot be deleted as it will create a collision between the **parent_of_current->something** category and then **current->something** category please either delete or rename one of these categories.

or should I have a warning:

> This action will create a collision between the **parent_of_current->something** category and then **current->something** category continuing will also delete the **current->something** category!

or is there something else I could do?

To be honest I like the second option, but I think that is liable to run into the same issue further down the chain if it creates another collision.

Comment: I would rename the offending category to show it needs attention. ie moving Sales, to where Sales already exists, it becomes Sales-1 or Sales-2, so the user would then need to rename it, and prevents loss of data. (like copying and pasting a file into the same directory) This way you can tell which was the original.

Comment: Depending on the application, might a user might expect that deleting a category would delete its child categories, hence no conflict problem? Could you explain your use case / application to describe why automatically moving child categories up to the parent's level would be expected/desirable behaviour?

Comment: @Waygood Please post your comment as an answer, otherwise I shall delete this question shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rename the offending category to show it needs attention. ie moving Sales, to where Sales already exists, it becomes Sales-1 or Sales-2, so the user would then need to rename it, and prevents loss of data. (like copying and pasting a file into the same directory) This way you can tell which was the original.